# Jquery get values from dynamically generated input texts

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Jquery get values from dynamically generated input texts**

This is an example of what I am trying to achieve. Let me put the html code and describe afterwards

```
<div class="col-xs-3 ">
                    <label for="pointMap[0]-value">firstkey</label>
                    <input type="text" id="pointMap[0]-value" name="pointsValueMap[firstkey]" value="value1">
                </div>
            
                <div class="col-xs-3 ">
                    <label for="pointMap[1]-value">secondkey</label>
                    <input type="text" id="pointMap[1]-value" name="pointsValueMap[secondkey]" value="value2">
                </div>
```

I would like to have all the values of however many of these kinds of input type text id (pointMap[i]-value). Please also suggest if there is a better way than having them an array when collected. My mind is blank on what should I be looping against, in a for loop, I am unable to find a terminating condition (size of these input texts).

Comment: Give them a common className and loop through that class

Comment: I will try it, thanks @charlietfl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery. You can use the [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/). There is whole list of such [selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) in jQuery.

You can store values of such inputs in an array like this

```js
var inputStore = []; //Where you want to store the values

$("input[name*=pointsValueMap]").each(function(){ //Will check for inputs with name containing pointsValueMap
  inputStore.push($(this).val())
});
```

Comment: What strategy would I use to have an associated array with the key as well? (See the keys that gets printed at top first key and second key? 
Thanks

Comment: Add some data attribute to the input box, `<input type="text" data-key="firstkey" ..` Then inside the jquery each function you can access it with `$(this).data('key')` and use it however you like.